# SQL Join on Comma Separated Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I have a table (example) like below:

```
| Hosts                                  | Description |
|------------------------------------------------------|
| 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2,192.168.0.3    | Group A     |
| 192.168.0.10,192.168.0.13,192.168.0.15 | Group B     |
| 192.168.0.22                           | Group C     |
|------------------------------------------------------|
```

I want to have this data in a new table:

```
| Hosts           | Description |
|-------------------------------|
| 192.168.0.1     | Group A     |
| 192.168.0.2     | Group A     |
| 192.168.0.3     | Group A     |
| 192.168.0.10    | Group B     |
| 192.168.0.13    | Group B     |
| 192.168.0.15    | Group B     |
| 192.168.0.22    | Group C     |
|-------------------------------|
```

What I did:

```
-- List comma separated hosts in a new table (this part is working good)

set @abc = (select hosts from example for xml path(''))
set @xyz = (select replace(replace(@abc,'<HOSTS>',','),'</HOSTS>',''))
select * into newtable from split(@xyz, ',')

--My Join

select newtable.item, example.description
from newtable
left join example on newtable.item like '%' + example.hosts + '%'
```

But I am getting:

```
| Hosts           | Description |
|-------------------------------|
| 192.168.0.1     | NULL        |
| 192.168.0.2     | NULL        |
| 192.168.0.3     | NULL        |
| 192.168.0.10    | NULL        |
| 192.168.0.13    | NULL        |
| 192.168.0.15    | NULL        |
| 192.168.0.22    | Group C     |
|-------------------------------|
```

Basically, my join is working only when my host value is alone on that row. I expected this resolved with my query "'%' + example.hosts + '%'" but no.
I tried to use the same logic using "cross apply" and "concatenate" but without success.

As you can see I don't have much knowledge in SQL and I have the impression that I'm missing something basic, even though I've been stuck in it for a long time.

I count on your help, thank you!

Comment: Why not fix your design, and use a noramalised approach? *That* is the real solution here.

Comment: There is no "split" function in tsql - so that must be something you or a coworker wrote. Splitting CSV strings (or any other using your choice of delimiter) is a common topic and has many solutions. Current versions of sql server have the [string_split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to do exactly that. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Larnu Can you let me know in more detail on how I should do this, as I mentioned unfortunately my knowledge is limited. Just to put you in context, I'm performing this query via logstash to integrate an old and unsupported software in my elasticsearch.

Comment: Basic database design means that a value represents an atomic value, @ramirkl ; that means not storing delimited data. Create multiple tables with 1 to many relationship. Read up on normalisation. You should, at a minimum, be aiming for achieving 3rd normal form; however, delimited data breaks first normal form.

Comment: @SMor forgot to mention, split was a function I had to add following another post here. I can't use string_split() in SQL 2014 as I researched. But this part is working fine, I can list the hosts that were separated by commas.

Comment: @Larnu, that's what the OP is doing, right?  His input is not 1NF, and his output is.  Giving him the benefit of the doubt, I assume he's not in a position to alter the process that gives rise to the data as he finds them, and is using SQL to produce a normalized table because that's the tool he has at his disposal.

Comment: @ramirkl: Change the left join in your query to `left join example on example.hosts like '%' + newtable.value + '%'` should do the trick.

Comment: It doesn't look like they want to fix the design to me, @JamesK.Lowden , just join a denomormalised table to a normalised one.

Comment: @ramirkl: "split was a function I had to add following another post here."  You should have added the link to that post, and the code used for that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is using XML and XQuery.

Notable points:

- No derived tables or CTEs.
- CData section protects against chars like ampersand, and the like.
- XPath expression contains `text()` for maximum performance. SQL Server peculiarity.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Hosts VARCHAR(1024), Description VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Hosts, Description) VALUES
('192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2,192.168.0.3', 'Group A'),
('192.168.0.10,192.168.0.13,192.168.0.15', 'Group B'),
('192.168.0.22', 'Group C');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT ID, [Description]
    ,x.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Hosts
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
          REPLACE(Hosts, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
          ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
    CROSS APPLY c.nodes ('/root/r') AS t2(x);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------+--------------+
| ID | Description |    Hosts     |
+----+-------------+--------------+
|  1 | Group A     |  192.168.0.1 |
|  1 | Group A     |  192.168.0.2 |
|  1 | Group A     |  192.168.0.3 |
|  2 | Group B     | 192.168.0.10 |
|  2 | Group B     | 192.168.0.13 |
|  2 | Group B     | 192.168.0.15 |
|  3 | Group C     | 192.168.0.22 |
+----+-------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do something like below:

```
SELECT Description,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') 'Hosts' 
FROM  
(
     SELECT Description, CAST ('<X>' + REPLACE(Hosts, ',', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data 
     FROM example     
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a)
```